# How to authenticate the JWT token in same Filter which was used to generate the token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on Spring Security so I am having issues in verifying the subsequent requests with the generated token.

As far I know once the user is logged in and token has been generated then for every subsequent requests how should I verify the token.

I basically means that in below class it has successfully generated a token and I added a cookie in the response just for testing purpose. Please have a look of below class.

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

public class AuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    private static final Logger log=Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

    public AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager autheticationManager) {
        this.setAuthenticationManager(autheticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        /*
         * List list = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(); GrantedAuthority auth = ()-> {
         * return "USER"; };
         * 
         * list.add(auth.getAuthority());
         */
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("user", "password"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.addHeader("Token", "Logged in");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Cookie cookies = new Cookie("token", "True");
        cookies.setMaxAge(60);
        session.setAttribute("cookie", cookies);
        log.log(Level.INFO, "Authentication Successull Cookies has been added to the session Context");
    }

}
```

Now, the further requests will be have to go through doFilterInternal method if I am not wrong?. Okay, so from here I can verify the token to authenticate the request and will decide if it has to pass or not. In order to override this method I will need to extend OncePerRequestFilter or BasicAuthenitcation class but in java we're limited and can only extend one class.

If we're thinking to implement a interface and in the interface we can implement the class then also it's not possible because the classes which is required are abstract so it will not be possible to implement them in interface.

If we're creating another class to implement this those class with method doFilterInternal then we will have to add this as filter in WebSecurityConfig class but as we all know it can add one filter only.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**")
        .hasRole("USER").and().formLogin()
        .and().addFilter(getAuthenticationFilter());
    }
```

So i am confused what to do at this point. please suggest something.

Comment: I did something with JWT recently, not java. I only can give you some suggestions. Use a API to generate JWT, just like the Login API. Use a "before filter" on all other APIs. Create a new API to refresh JWT.

Comment: That's what I thought initially, so both action token generation and token authentication can't be done on same classes, am I correct? But for that I will have to write a microservice architecture. Because I will have to allow all the request from a central api because there I will have to authenticate the user to generate token then let the requests access to their destination application.

Comment: Its better to do it in separate classes. What you are doing is correct, you only need to extend OncePerRequestFilter and define the authentication logic there. UsernamePasswordAuthentication should ideally be invoked once when the user logs in.

Comment: Sorry, but that filter will not be added to the configure method so how it will be invoked ? Please given an example if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this, We can generate the tokens and verify it within the same class we do not need any other API's to be involved because if you're using micro-services architecture then you will have to mess a lot.

So what I did is, I created a custom Filter class below.

AutheticationFilter.class

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

public class AuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    private static final Logger log=Logger.getAnonymousLogger();

    protected AuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login", "POST"));
        this.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        String user = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        log.log(Level.INFO, "Username from the Request: "+user);
        log.log(Level.INFO, "Password from the request: "+password);

        /*
         * List list = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(); GrantedAuthority auth = ()-> {
         * return "USER"; };
         * 
         * list.add(auth.getAuthority());
         */
        return getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("user", "password"));
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("Do filter authentication filter invoked");
        super.doFilter(req, res, chain);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println("Authentication Successull Cookies has been added to the session Context");
        response.addHeader("Token", "Logged in");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        Cookie cookies = new Cookie("token", "True");
        cookies.setMaxAge(60);
        session.setAttribute("cookie", cookies);
        log.log(Level.INFO, "Authentication Successull Cookies has been added to the session Context");
    }

}
```

Add this filter to your config class using add filter before method of Http Security.